# Best practice doctrine user friend relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Whats the best way to create a friend relationship in doctrine.

My following way would be.

User.xml.orm:

```
    <many-to-many field="friends" target-entity="MyEntity\User">
        <join-table name="my_friends">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="idAUsers" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" nullable="false" />
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="idBUsers" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" nullable="false" />
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

User.php

```
public function getFriends() {
    $friends = $this->getAUsers();
    foreach ($this->getBUsers() as $bUser) {
         $friends[] = $bUser;
    }
    return $friends;
}
```

As you see I need to merge the two UserFriend and join everytime both when create a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a self referencing many to many.

The [doctrine documentation example](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) seems very apt given it's dealing with exactly your scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I can work with this but its more a twitter follower relationship then a facebook friend relationship when I understand this correctly. I did use it that I only show as friend in the my api when its in myFriend and friendWithMe, else its a friend request, sent(only in friends) or received(only in friendWithMe).